# Jersey & Spring Boot turns non-ok response statuses to 404

Tags: jersey, spring-boot

I am using Jersey with Spring Boot 1.2.5. I have a Jersey controller (annotated with `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`) which works fine and returns JSON as long as I return an ok response such as

```
return Response.ok(dto).build();
```

but whenever I try to return a custom error status such as

```
return Response.status(Status.CONFLICT).build();
```

it gets turned into a 404 such as

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
    <p>Problem accessing /error. Reason:

        <pre>    Not Found</pre>
    </p>
    <hr>
        <i>
            <small>Powered by Jetty://</small>
        </i>
        <hr/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jersey status code bug?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597274/jersey-status-code-bug)

Answer (score 1):

Jersey expects the response to contain an entity. If I return an empty map together with my error code, the error gets passed onto the browser with an empty JSON object.

```
return Response.status(Status.CONFLICT).entity(new HashMap<>()).build();
```

If you have any better solutions, please feel free to comment.