# Jersey returns 404 with any error status code?

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, jersey-2.0, rest-assured

I have this useless endpoint in path "/test":

```
@PUT
public Response doSomething() {
  return Response.status(409).build();
}
```

and I test it this way:

```
@Test
public void uselessTest() {
  put("/test").then().assertThat().statusCode(409);
}
```

But I get an assertion error:

> Expected status code <409> doesn't match actual status code <404>.

This happens in more codes: 400, 500... apart from 200.

I'm using Spring Boot. If I put a breakpoint in my endpoint method when I run the test, execution stops there, so the request in the test is done properly. If I change the status code (in resource and in the test, too) to 200, test passes.

What is happening?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The default behavior with Jersey, when there is an error status (4xx, 5xx), is to use the servlet's `Response.sendError`, which results in a redirect to an error page. Since there is no error page set up, it results in a 404.

We can change this behavior by setting the Jersey property

> [`ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/snapshot/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR)

You can do this in your `ResourceConfig` subclass

```
public JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        property(ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR, true);
    }
}
```

Or (with Spring Boot) you can add it in your `application.properties` file.

```
spring.jersey.init.jersey.config.server.response.setStatusOverSendError=true
```

Comment: Or you can add it to the `web.xml` file, as an `<init-param>` of your Jersey `ServletContainer` servlet. Thank you

Comment: `jersey.config.server.response.setStatusOverSendError`. That is the string value of the constant if you want to use it in a web.xml.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem as well, and solved it by excluding ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration from the spring boot auto config:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class })
```