# Servlet(Jersey2), send error message from filter class in json form

Tags: servlets, jersey, jax-rs, servlet-filters

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(erresp);
        svltresp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        svltresp.setContentType("application/json");
        PrintWriter writer = svltresp.getWriter();
        writer.println(jsonInString);
```

i am not sure this is best or not but found the way.

I am working on a Jersey2 Application.

Here is my error model class

@XmlRootElement(name = "ErrorResponse")
public class ErrorResponse {

```
@XmlElement
private String errorInstanceId;

@XmlElement
private String errorCode;

@XmlElement
private String errorMessage;

@XmlElement
private String errorAdditionalDescription;

public String getErrorInstanceId() {
    return errorInstanceId;
}

public void setErrorInstanceId(String errorInstanceId) {
    this.errorInstanceId = errorInstanceId;
}

public String getErrorCode() {
    return errorCode;
}

public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) {
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
}

public String getErrorMessage() {
    return errorMessage;
}

public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
}

public String getErrorAdditionalDescription() {
    return errorAdditionalDescription;
}

public void setErrorAdditionalDescription(String errorAdditionalDescription) {
    this.errorAdditionalDescription = errorAdditionalDescription;
}

public ErrorResponse() {
}

public ErrorResponse(String errorInstanceId, String errorCode, String errorMessage, String errorAdditionalDetails) {
    this.errorInstanceId = errorInstanceId;
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    this.errorAdditionalDescription = errorAdditionalDetails;
}
```

}

and i am sending error message in json

```
ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "error",
                "Failed", null);
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(400).entity(errorResponse).build());
```

but the question i have is that,

when i write that source code in the servlet, it works fine, i can see the error in json format, However, when i write that in filter class, i only can see in normal apache html error page.

Could anyone explain what is going on here and suggest me any solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try setting [this property](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36600434/2587435)

Comment: since i am not using JerseyConfig class(using web.xml), could you please explain where to put application.properties file and let my application read this ?

Comment: That's only for spring boot. If you are using web.xml, just set it as an `init-param` to your Jersey servlet. If you click the link to the javadoc of the ServleProperties, you should see the string value (`jersey.config.server.response.setStatusOverSendError`) you can use for the init-param name

Comment: ok i tried, and still only can see html error page not in json format.

Comment: and actually why i need to put that property param into servlet?? i want to implement it from filter class though?

Answer (score 0):

When the exception is thrown from resource or servlet, based on the `MIME media type` in  [`@Produces`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Produces.html), response will be produced accordingly.

If the exception is thrown from filters(outside resource), we should add `media type` explicitly to response object.

```
Response.ResponseBuilder response = Response.status(400).entity(errorResponse);
response = response.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
throw new WebApplicationException(response.build());
```

Comment: i followed as what you said, however, still getting HTML page but i found a way, i added to the post