# jersey: how to configura jersey to return jsons only

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey-2.0

One API endpoint is using the following annotations:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

When request content-type is not `application/json`, the server will return status code 415 but the response content-type is `text/html;charset=utf-8`.

How to configuration jersey to return json as default content-type? Thanks

Comment: The reason you are getting HTML is because there is an actual error page returned by the server, not Jersey. To fix, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36600434/2587435).

Answer (score 0):

I personally have never tried to do exactly what you are asking but this can be done by the  use of [Interceptors](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9505)

You are in particularly looking for WriterInterceptor

> Writer interceptors are used for cases where entity is written to the
>   "wire" which on the server means when writing out a response entity
>   and on the client side when writing request entity for a request to be
>   sent out to the server

This means when ever your client is sending the response WriterInterceptor will be called. Here you have the power to modify (JSONify) the response.