# Jersey validation error getting 404 instead of 400

Tags: java, rest, validation, jersey

I have a controller using `javax.validation.constraints.Size`, I was surprised that instead of a 400 status code, I am getting a 404.

I did some debugging and the `ValidationExceptionMapper` IS being invoked on a `ConstraintValidationException` and IS creating a response with a status code of 400. HOWEVER, I also have an `ExceptionMapper<Throwable>` registered and THIS `ExceptionMapper` is getting a `NotFoundException` AFTER the `ValidationExceptionMapper` returns its response of 400.

Interestingly, if I set `BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE` to `true` I get the 400 instead of the 404.

It almost seems like the built response is not valid unless `BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE` is `true`.

I am using:

```
* spring-boot-starter-jersey: 1.5.9.RELEASE
* jersey-server: 2.25.1
```

[Jersey ValidationExceptionMapper source](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/ext/bean-validation/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/validation/internal/ValidationExceptionMapper.java)

Comment: What does the `ValidationExceptionMapper` look like?

Comment: @CassioMazzochiMolin Link added, but it is Jersey's default class

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36597274/2587435

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Thanks!