# @Valid is not working with jax rs and springboot

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, jersey, jax-rs

I am getting `NotFoundException` while trying to implement custom exception handling in spring-boot rest application.

The code was working fine when I was using MVC (using `@ControllerAdvice`) annotations but not sure when I am sending a data which is violating the constraint mentioned in entity(pojo class) it is throwing only `NotFoundException` (for all validation failure) but not the `MethodViolationException` or `ConstraintViolationException`

I am not able to send the message for that particular violation.

Not sure where I am making this mistake. Please help

Code:

```
@POST
@Path("/customers/add") 
public Response addCustomer(@Valid customer cust) 
{

// Rest of the code

}
```

POJO:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cust")
public class Customer
{
  @NotNull
  @Size(min=1,max=50,message ="invalid name") 
  String name;
```

}

Exception Handler:

```
@Provider
public class CustomHandler implements ExceptionMapper<Exception>
{
 public Response toResponse(Exception ex) 
 {
  if(ex instanceOf ConstraintViolationException) 
  {
    Do something
  } 
}
```

**UPDATE 1

If I enable the send_error_in_response i am getting the message for this but not sure why my custom exception handler is not able to catch this exception and only throwing NotFoundException

Comment: Read the [Bean Validation chapter](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html) in the Jersey docs.

Comment: Are you getting a 404 for all error codes, or just the bean validation errors?

Comment: @Paul Samsotha yes right now i am testing only for validation and getting this 404 error. Where i am throwing exception explicitly there i am getting it in expected format in response but not for any validation error

Comment: _"but not sure why my custom exception handler is not able to catch this exception"_ - It's because Jersey already has [a mapper](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/2.28-RELEASE/ext/bean-validation/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/validation/internal/ValidationExceptionMapper.java#L50). I think you are getting the not found because of [this (but not sure)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36600434/2587435)

Comment: I have added a separate handler for ConstraintViolationException which resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Try Handling Exception Using:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class CustomizedResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(StudentNotFoundException)
  public final ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> handleUserNotFoundException(StudentNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {
    ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), ex.getMessage(),
        request.getDescription(false));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
  }
```

For more information you might want to refer http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-validation-for-rest-services

Comment: It was working when I was using @ControllerAdvice but it's not working when I am trying to implement with jersey.